# How to rename a custom source APT repository?

Tags: debian, apt

In my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ I have these lines:

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:/fish:/release:/3/Debian_9.0/ /

deb http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt stretch main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt stretch main
```

I don't find how we can give a "name" to these additional sources. The original repos have names like "oldstable" but how to add a custom name to these? it's listed as "unknown"...

If I type `apt list -a percona-server-server fish`, I get these:

```
fish/stretch-backports,now 3.0.2-2~bpo9+1 amd64 [installed]
fish/unknown 3.0.2-1 amd64
fish/oldstable 2.4.0-1 amd64

percona-server-server/unknown 5.6.45-86.1-1.stretch amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this cannot be done.

The identifier in the output of `apt list` is derived from the *Suite* metadata information in the `Release` or  `InRelease` file of the repository and cannot be overwritten locally.

```
$ curl -s -L https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/Release | grep "^Suite:"
Suite: oldstable
$ curl -s -L https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-backports/Release | grep "^Suite:"
Suite: stretch-backports
```

Neither of your repositories have the field set in their `Release` file which is why apt defaults to `unknown`.

```
$ curl -s -L https://repo.percona.com/percona/apt/dists/stretch/Release | grep "^Suite:"
$ curl -s -L https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:/fish:/release:/3/Debian_9.0/Release | grep "^Suite:"
$
```

Comment: alright, thank you and I thought it was something like that too, but then how am I supposed to use "aptitude install fish -t XXX" where XXX is opensuse? it's impossible right? the -t for target

Comment: 1. You may specify the version: `apt install fish=3.0.2-1`  
2. Unless you played around with apt-pinning `apt install fish` will install the right version.   `apt-cache policy fish` and `man apt_preferences`will tell you why.

Comment: i effectively changed the priorities in apt-pinning and also I'm not aware of the version in the repo (it's for automatic installation) :( that's why having the the source repo "name" would be useful, like when I do "apt install fish -t testing"